# .htaccess Completely rewrite URL to show file in a folder, rather than page in root

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, I have the current file structure:

```
ROOT
    -> /public
        -> /user_views
            user_handle.php
            user_profile.php
            user_feed.php
            user_settings.php
    .htaccess
```

As you see, the folder `user_views` contains a few of the possible views that the client could want to look at. What I am wanting, is for clients that insert the URL `http://example.com/user/` to be directed to the page `user_handle.php`. This `handle` would act as a root file for all `/user/` pages, and it would accordingly split into those pages through numerous `$_GET` requests.

So far, I have the following .htaccess, but it's not working...

```
RewriteRule ^user/ user_views/user_handle.php [L]
```

What could I do to get this to work, so that the url `http://example.com/user` redirects to the `user_handle` file in the `user_views` folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it seems you would like to make `user_handle.php` located under `public/user_views` act as a "router" for the rest of you PHP files and have all requests to /user/ (e.g. /user/?page=1) be processed by `user_handle.php`.

If that's the case, your rule seems legit. The only thing I noticed (I might be wrong) is that your `.htaccess` is located outside the `public` folder. In that's the case, you need to include 'public/' as part of your rule.

I recreated the folder/file structure you described and it has worked for me using the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/ public/user_views/user_handle.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Slight chance this is the problem, but you also might want to double check that `mod_rewrite`, which is the rule-based rewriting engine is enabled on your server/local environment. It should show up under 'Loaded modules' when you call `phpinfo()` in any PHP file.

Hope this helps.